# ContentObserver Not Working on Api level 17

Tags: android, contacts, contentobserver

I want to detect change when contact get modified/added and deleted. So My Code is working fine on api level 23 and and api 22 but it is not working on api level 17.So please help me on this.

Here is My Content Observer Code.

```
public class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

        public MyContentObserver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            this.onChange(selfChange, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {

            Log.d("Change", "Yes");
        }

    }
```

and Code to Register Content Observer:

```
myContentObserver = new MyContentObserver(new Handler());
        try {
            getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()
                    .registerContentObserver(
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true,
                            myContentObserver);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "is not working" means. What are your **exact** symptoms, and how are you testing?

Comment: I am trying to detect contact changes when u add/edit/delete contact in phone then it will log change yes but in api level 17 it is not detecting change. So please help me on that.